# WP8 ListBox without scrolling

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, listbox

In a WP8 app I want to use an "Item Container" without scrolling. The reason is that the app dynamically adds and removes items so that the size of that list changes. I want the control, that holds the items to adjust its height depending on the number of items. ListBox so far provides me with all those requirements. However, ListBox itself contains a scroll viewer. So when I want to scroll up or down on the page I need to make sure that I don't touch the ListBox as this will just scroll the ListBox's items. The reason I'm using ListBox instead of a StackPanel or Grid is that the XAML code binds to an observable collection via ItemsSource. I don't want to loose that binding.

Question: Is there any way to disable scrolling in a ListBox? Is there any alternative Item Container (3rd party maybe or in the framework)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to disable ListBox's scrolling use ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility=Disabled
and ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility=Disabled.

You can add any other scroll viewer to your page using this your list box wont scroll.